# How to format a text with different description logic symbols?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I have the following:

```
\textbf{Example 1.2:} In figure 1, \(Joint\_Structure \in SNOMED CT\) 
while \(FMA\models\neg(Joint\equiv set\_of\_Joints)\). If the mappings 
\(Joint\_Structure,Joint,\equiv)\) and \(Joint\_Structure 
Sets\_of\_Joints},\equiv)\) exist in the final alignment, the mappings 
should be flagged as unstable since they introduce new relationship 
\(Sets\_of\_Joints\equiv Joint\) in the merged ontology that is not 
entailed in FMA which is the origin of the entities.
```

When I compile it, LaTeX places large places between words. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You should use `\text{Joint}` etc. for text inside math mode

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Maybe worth to mention, that `\text` is provided my the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Well, maybe, but for posts with such fragments there's not much help to provide.

Answer (score 6):

You have very wide objects to print, with rather narrow line length.

I can reproduce the bad spacing (with fixes for avoiding wrong fonts). Note that explicit numbers are not recommended: better using higher level methods, that make the source independent of the actually assigned numbers.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newcommand{\lvar}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{theorem}
Some statement
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}
In figure~\ref{jointstr}, \(\lvar{Joint\_Structure} \in \lvar{SNOMEDCT}\) 
while \(\lvar{FMA}\models\neg(\lvar{Joint}\equiv \lvar{set\_of\_Joints})\).
If the mappings \((\lvar{Joint\_Structure},\lvar{Joint},\equiv)\) and 
\((\lvar{Joint\_Structure},\lvar{Sets\_of\_Joints},\equiv)\) exist in the 
final alignment, the mappings should be flagged as unstable since they 
introduce new relationship \(\lvar{Sets\_of\_Joints}\equiv \lvar{Joint}\) in the 
merged ontology that is not entailed in \(\lvar{FMA}\) which is the origin 
of the entities.
\end{example}


\begin{figure}
\centering
A figure

\caption{A caption\label{jointstr}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's not really much you can do. A possible strategy would be, in these tough situations to make the space around relation symbols to have some shrinkability. If I do

```
\begin{example}
\setlength\thickmuskip{5mu plus 5mu minus 3mu} % local setting
In figure~\ref{jointstr}, \(\lvar{Joint\_Structure} \in \lvar{SNOMEDCT}\)
while \(\lvar{FMA}\models\neg(\lvar{Joint}\equiv \lvar{set\_of\_Joints})\).
```

(with the rest unvaried), I get

[image]

However, rewording is usually the best strategy. You're the best judge about how to do it.

Comment: you are indeed a genius, God bless you

Answer (score 5):

I’d like to add a remark to @egreg excellent answer: when the line-breaking task becomes really tough, as in this case, you might want to allow breaks at places where you wouldn’t ordinarily do.  Given your text, I’m able to avoid underfull `\hbox`es altogether by doing the following:

- permitting formulas to be broken after commas
  (this is normally prohibited);
- permitting identifiers of logical variables to be broken after
  underscores;
- explicitly indicating additional points
  where words can be hyphenated.

Allow me some remarks about the last point.  Although TeX does not automatically hyphenate “words” in math mode, an explicit `\discretionary{...}{...}{}` *is* permitted in that mode, and behave as expected (the third field *must* be empty, see *The TeXbook*, p. 292); but unfortunately, both `\mathit{...}` and `\textit{...}` (or `\mathrm{...}` and `\textrm{...}`), when used in math mode, introduce additional levels of boxing that inhibits the discretionary break.  It would be possible to make up for this in the case of `\mathit` (or `\mathrm`), but, on the other hand, identifiers like “Set_of_Joints” are best typeset using `\textit` (or `\textrm`), because of the way italic correction is handled in math mode (for the details, see *The TeXbook*, Appendix G, Rule 14), and of the effects this handling has on combinations like “f_” (yes, this *is* a minor flaw in @egreg’s answer).  Ther remedy is to jump in and out of math mode, as exemplified by the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newcommand{\lvar}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\newcommand*{\brul}{\discretionary{\_}{}{\_}}



\begin{document}

\section{A section title}

\begin{theorem}
Some statement
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}
    % Local settings:
    \binoppenalty = \exhyphenpenalty
    \relpenalty = \exhyphenpenalty
    % We disable on purpose egreg's remedy, to emphasize the effects of ours:
    % \setlength\thickmuskip{5mu plus 5mu minus 3mu} % local setting
    In figure~\ref{jointstr}, \(\lvar{Joint\_Struc\-ture} \in
    \lvar{SNO}\)\lvar{\-MED CT} while \(\lvar{FMA}\models\neg(\lvar{Joint}\equiv
    \lvar{set\_}\)\lvar{\brul of\brul Joints}$)$.  If the mappings
    $($\lvar{Joint\_Struc\-}\(\lvar{ture},\allowbreak \lvar{Joint},\allowbreak
    {\equiv})\) and $($\lvar{Joint\brul Struc\-}\(\lvar{ture},\allowbreak
    \lvar{Sets}\)\lvar{\brul of\brul}\(\lvar{Joints},\allowbreak \equiv)\) exist
    in the final alignment, the mappings should be flagged as unstable since
    they introduce new relationship \lvar{Sets\brul
    of\brul}\(\lvar{Joints}\equiv \lvar{Joint}\) in the merged ontology that is
    not entailed in \(\lvar{FMA}\) which is the origin of the entities.
\end{example}

Compare \( \textit{Set\_of\_Joints} \) with \( \mathit{Set\_of\_Joints} \): the
latter includes the italic correction after the~``\textit{f}''.

\begin{figure}
\centering
A figure

\caption{A caption\label{jointstr}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It should be noted, however, that this will work as expected (if and) only if the `\mathsurround` parameter is equal to zero (as it normally is in LaTeX).

In cases like these, anyway, you should consider displaying at least some of the formulas.

Here’s the output of our code sample:

[image: Output of sample code]